# How to tell which users are running which reports?

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I apologize if this isnt the right domain. I searched all the stack exchange communities.

I'm using Microsoft PowerBI and would like to know which of the reports created are being run and by which users?

Comment: Please review this topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-modern-usage-metrics

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-auditing